httpclient BaseAddress localhost Refers to webserver localhost or client localhost?
I have a webpage on a web server A with a line of code like this:
httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");

to call a Web API on my localhost.
As I want to make a webpage communicate with a client-side installed service/api/application, does it call the web server A machine localhost or client machine localhost? Thank you

Hello Martin, what do you mean by having the httpclient on the webpage? Is it part of a Razor Page? Or is it called in the code behind, e.g. OnGet or the contorller action?

A asp.net c# webform to call a asp.net web api/web service. My intention is to browse to that webpage which will call a client-side web api/service.

"httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");" in my webform cs file will refer to the webserver localhost or client machine localhost? If invoke the call through javascript, can it be done (call to client-side localhost)?

Using an HttpClient to call localhost from the code behind your webforms page will make requests to the server machine. So, if you have another web app listening on port 64195, the following address is valid:
httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");

However, if you call the same address from a JavaScript file, the web page will make a request to the client machine, since localhost here refers to the address of whatever machine making the call.
If you want to make a call from your JavaScript file to your other web app, consider using the domain name or some sort of proxy, e.g. fetch(example.com:64195/api/path)

I think you are struggling with the network principle, here's a quick sketch:

In this case, if the server runs in the same machine (basically), it will work. However, if the server runs somewhere else, this will not work, and to make it work, you might need to purchase a domain and a server (so that you can get a Public IP), or you can try intranet penetration such as Cloudflare Tunnel.
